# Error: File not found with name : -a while using getopts

Tags: linux, unix, getopts

I am Having trouble using getopts where i am trying to parsing options but getting error:

**Error: File not found with name : -a**

Code:

```
while getopts ":a :b :c :d :e :f :g" opt; do

case $opt in

        a) FILETOPARSE=$OPTARG
           echo $compactAlarms
            ;;
        b) FILETOPARSE=${OPTARG}
           echo $nodeAlarms
            ;;
        c) FILETOPARSE=${OPTARG}
           echo $severityAlarms
            ;;
        d) FILETOPARSE=${OPTARG}
           echo $csvGentrator
            ;;
        e) FILETOPARSE=${OPTARG}
           echo $tableData
            ;;
        f) FILETOPARSE=${OPTARG}
           echo $help
            ;;
        g) FILETOPARSE=${OPTARG}
           echo $exit_function
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Error wrong Syntax,Opening help" && help
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Once it parses the data it'll call the function and display the data.

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces in option string. I think thats the problem.

```
while getopts ":a:b:c:d:e:f:g:" opt; do
```

should sove your issue. Complete script like this

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a:b:c:d:e:f:g:" opt; do
case "${opt}" in

        a) FILETOPARSE=$OPTARG
           echo $compactAlarms
            ;;
        b) FILETOPARSE=${OPTARG}
           echo $nodeAlarms
            ;;
        c) FILETOPARSE=${OPTARG}
           echo $severityAlarms
            ;;
        d) FILETOPARSE=${OPTARG}
           echo $csvGentrator
            ;;
        e) FILETOPARSE=${OPTARG}
           echo $tableData
            ;;
        f) FILETOPARSE=${OPTARG}
           echo $help
            ;;
        g) FILETOPARSE=${OPTARG}
           echo $exit_function
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Error wrong Syntax,Opening help" && help
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: It is not working as u see Space doesn't matter . I am getting same error again.

Comment: Given that the OP seems to expect option `g` to take an argument, I think the desired option string is `a:b:c:d:e:f:g:`.  The leading colon has a special meaning, and does not apply to the `a`.

Comment: William' s comment is valid and I updated the code and please try running with that.